# Display data from two arrays using php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
$listx= array('a','b')

$listy= array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven')
```

I would like to display array data in the format given below:

a one,

b two,

a three,

b four,

a five,

b six,

a seven

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Smells of homework a little. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this example:

```
$listx= array('a','b');

$listy= array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven');

$i= 0;
foreach($listy as $value){

if($i == 2){
$i = 0; // reset as 0
}
echo $listx[$i] . " ". $value ."<br>";

$i++;
}
```

**Explanation**:

In this example most important thing is that you must know what is this:

```
if($i == 2)
{ 
   $i = 0; // reset as 0 
}
```

When `$i` is equal to **2** than you must need to reset as **0** otherwise you will get the **undefined** index or offset notices.

Comment: Thank you for the help!!

Comment: @pawan-kumar-singh glad to help u don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

As your question ,a position is the divisible by 2 in keys value of $listy array ..

```
 foreach ($listy as $key => $value) {
    ($key % 2 == 0) ? var_dump($listx[0].$value):var_dump($listx[1].$value);        
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!!